# How to store location data outside of windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, cloud, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a windows phone application which will track user movements and collects some statistics. I want to store this information at some place (if user permits and this data wont shared with anyone) so that I can read that data again.

Any ideas on how I can do this in windows phone ?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a web service. You can use Azure Mobile Services, your own hosted or on Azure web service. Or you can use any other number of services such as Buddy or Parse. It's up to you to decide depending on the pricing and features of each service.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/#) to store data off to the cloud.  There's a [tutorial here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-wp8/) for Windows 8.  It looks like you've tagged the question with Windows Phone 7, though, which the mobile services package isn't available for (that I know of).  In that case you can create a webservice that your phone app can send data to, which can then store it wherever it pleases - a database, Azure Table storage, or wherever.

Answer (score 0):

you have three options

1 ) If you want to store it locally then use : IsolatedStorage for Windows Phone.
2 ) If you want it to be somewhere outside your device : Write your own service code and connect it to a database (one end) and give a call to it from your windows device (other end)

Service not necessarily has to be Azure ... You can write any service connect it to ur database and store the value there.